# Are there any Combinatoric proofs of Bertrand's postulate?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I feel like there must exist a combinatoric proof of a theorem like: There is a prime between $n$ and $2n$, or $p$ and $p^2$ or anything similar to this stronger than there is a prime between $p$ and $(\prod_p p) + 1$ (Euclid's theorem).

I was trying to prove one by the Sieve on this grid

```
    1     2     3     4 ... p
  p+1   p+2   p+3   p+4 ... 2p
 2p+1  2p+2  2p+3  2p+4 ... 3p
...........................
...........................
........................... p^2
p^2+1 p^2+2 p^2+3 p^2+4 ...
```

but it did not work.

Do any good arguments like this exist? I don't expect anything as strong as Prime Number Theorem or even Bertrand, but surely a direct combination proof can prove that there are lots of primes?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what counts as a combinatorial argument, but it's certainly a phrase I associate with the work of Erdos.  So I will note that Erdos, at a very young age, gave a new proof of Bertrand's Postulate.  You might want to check that out and see if it is "combinatorial enough" for your purposes or tastes.

Comment: To add a reference to @Pete's comment: An extremely nice exposition of Erdős's argument can be found in Aigner and Ziegler's book *Proofs from THE BOOK* (which I heartily recommend to anyone liking beautiful and outstandingly clever mathematics, which is in addition written and exposed with great care for details). The title refers to a phrase of PE about which you can find out on his [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erdős) in case you're interested.

Comment: Chebyshev said/And I say it again/There's always a prime/Between $n$ and $2n$.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an elementary argument which shows that there are "lots" of primes. Consider the number of numbers in the interval $[1, n]$. On the one hand, this is $n$. On the other hand, by unique factorization every such number can be uniquely written in the form $\prod_{i=1}^{\pi(n)} p_i^{e_i}$. It follows that $n$ is equal to the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$e_1 \log p_1 + ... + e_{\pi(n)} \log p_{\pi(n)} \le \log n.$$

This is easily seen to be at most $\left( \log_2 n \right)^{\pi(n)}$, hence

$$n \le (\log_2 n)^{\pi(n)}$$

from which it follows that

$$\pi(n) \ge \frac{\log n}{\log \log_2 n}.$$

It might be possible to extract a weak form of Bertrand's postulate from this argument.

Comment: It tells us there are at least 4 primes below 100000? edit: this is better than Euclids proof which gives $\pi(n) \ge \log(\log(n))$.

Comment: Well, there are!

Answer (score 11):

Interesting idea to use a grid.  I doubt it will work for this question, since writing things in that grid format in a sense splits into arithmetic progressions modulo $p$, and usually saying things about the primes in a progression is harder.

However, I cannot help but mention that using a grid like that was applied brilliantly by Maier to prove a counter-intuitive result, (using the Prime Number Theorem for Arithmetic Progessions) and the idea is now called the Maier Matrix Method.

(A small digression, but it is interesting!)

**The Maier Matrix Method**

There are questions regarding primes in short intervals, and we can ask ourselves what does $$\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)$$ look like?  To say anything meaningful, $y$ cannot be too small, but here lets suppose $y=\log^B(x)$ for some $B>2$.  Selberg proved that under the Riemann Hypothesis, we have $$\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)\sim \frac{y}{\log x}$$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ for almost all $x$. (A set with density $\rightarrow 1$)  It was then conjectured that this asymptotic must hold for all $x$ which are sufficiently large.  (This conjecture was made for several reasons, one of which is that it is true under Cramer's probabilistic model)

In a surprising turn of events, Maier showed it was false, and that there exists $\delta>0$ and arbitrarily large values of $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that both $$\pi(x_1 +\log^B (x_1))-\pi (x_1)> (1+\delta)\log^{B-1}(x_1)$$and $$\pi(x_2 +\log^B (x_2))-\pi (x_2)< (1-\delta)\log^{B-1}(x_2)$$hold, despite the fact that the asymptotic holds for a set of density $1$.

He proved this using a method which is now called the "Maier Matrix Method."  Essentially, it is just drawing a grid which is similar to the one above, and then applying a clever combinatorial argument.  The columns are arithmetic progressions, and by PNT4AP, we can easily say things about them to understand the number of primes in the grid.  There is a little trick with oscillation of the Dickman Function, but then basically by the pigeon hole principle the question is solved.

I definitely think you might find this [expository article](http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/icm.pdf) by Dr.Andrew Granville to be interesting.  (It is quite readable, and gives an a more in depth, and very clear explanation)

Answer (score 10):

> **Edited:** Here is a very relevant [link](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/bertrand.pdf) on Robin Chapman's page.  It is the combinatorial proof which Erdos originally used to prove Bertrands postulate.  (Mentioned in Pete L. Clark's comment)
>
> The PDF is *very* similar to the proofs I mentioned here, (and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/link-summary-proof-of-chebyshev-statement-sum-p-leq-n-frac-log-pp-sim/33995#33995))  and is based entirely on the primes dividing the central binomial coefficient.
>
> I will leave in the proof regarding a lower bound for $\pi(x)$, since it is still relevant.

What follows is a proof Chebyshev's Theorem based on the primes dividing the central binomial coefficient.  First, two well known facts:

**Fact 1:** Let $r(n,p)$ denote the highest power of a prime $p$ that divides $n!$. Then $$r(n,p)=\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^{3}}\right\rfloor+\cdots$$

**Fact 2:** For every integer $N\geq1$ we have that $$\frac{4^{N}}{2N}\leq\binom{2N}{N}.$$

**Theorem:** *We have that* $$\pi(x)\geq\ln(2)\frac{x}{\ln x}-2.$$

*Proof.* Consider $\binom{2N}{N}.$ For each prime $p$, let $v_{p}$ denote the number of times it divides $\binom{2N}{N}$. Hence $$\binom{2N}{N}=\prod_{p\leq2N}p^{v_{p}}.$$ Let $t=\log_{p}(2N)$ so that $\left\lfloor\frac{2N}{p^{j}}\right\rfloor=0$ when $j\geq t.$ By the lemma, we have $$v_{p}=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{2N}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{2N}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor+\cdots\right)-2\left(\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^{2}}\right\rfloor+\cdots\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{t}\left\lfloor\frac{2N}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor.$$ Since $\left\lfloor\frac{2N}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor=0$ or $\left\lfloor\frac{2N}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac{N}{p^{i}}\right\rfloor=1$ for each $i$ we see that $v_{p}\leq t.$ Hence if $p^{r}$ divides $\binom{2N}{N}$ we must have $p^{r}\leq2N.$  Consequently $$\binom{2N}{N}=\prod_{p\leq2N}p^{v_{p}}\leq\prod_{p\leq2N}(2N)=(2N)^{\pi(2N)}.$$Applying the other lemma we get $\frac{4^{N}}{2N}\leq(2N)^{\pi(2N)}$and upon taking logarithms we find$$N\ln4-\ln(2N)\leq\pi(2N)\ln(2N)$$and hence $$\frac{2N\ln2}{\ln2N}\leq\pi(2N)+1.$$Since this holds for every even integer, and there is at most one prime between even integers we get

$$\frac{x\ln2}{\ln x}-2\leq\pi(x)\ \text{for all } \ x\geq2,$$ as desired.

Comment: A very similar proof can be used to give a similar upper bound; it can be found, for example, in Apostol's _Introduction to Analytic Number Theory_ (the section is titled something like "elementary results").

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95766/chebyshev-proof-prod-limits-p-leq-2k-p-2k/95783#95783