# How find this function $f(x)=ae^{ex}$ other solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

let $f(x)$ such
$$f'(x)=f\left(x+\dfrac{1}{e}\right)$$

I found this problem one solution(maybe have other)

Let $f(x)=ae^{bx}$
then
we have
$$abe^{bx}=ae^{bx+\dfrac{b}{e}}\Longrightarrow ae^{bx}(b-e^{b/e})\Longrightarrow b=e$$
so
$$y=ae^{ex}$$
is one solution? and How find other solution? Thank you

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be any more solutions. It's a first order (delay) ODE after all, and you've already found a suitable one-parameter family of solutions.

Comment: Yes,This is ODE,I think this is one solution.if no,How can prove this is only solution,Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differential equations that are also functional](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/45392/53845).

Comment: This question has an open bounty and cannot be closed. Wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See **[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45392/differential-equations-that-are-also-functional)**. Yes, this is an answer. You should find more or less everything you need in the linked thread.