# Proofs from the BOOK: Bertrand's postulate Part 3: $\frac{2}{3}n<p \leq n \rightarrow$ no p divides $\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have a very hard proof from "Proofs from the BOOK". It's the section about Bertrand's postulate, [page 9](http://books.google.com/books?id=CuTpgZaLahkC&pg=PA9#v=onepage&q&f=false):

I have to show, that for $\frac{2}{3}n<p \leq n$ there is no p which divides $\binom{2n}{n}$. I know $$\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$$ and from $\frac{2}{3}n<p \leq n$ I follow $3p>2n$. Then $(2n)!$ has only the prime factors $p$ and $2p$ (because $3p>2n$) and $n!$ has only the prime factor $p$. At this point the author goes on to the next part of the proof.

Can someone explain to me, how the argument about the $p's$ proofs the statement, that there is no $p$ which divides $\binom{2n}{n}$?

I hope my question is clear and sorry for my bad English.
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Take a look at this MSE page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38917/are-there-any-combinatoric-proofs-of-weak-versions-of-bertrands-postulate

Comment: Or better yet, take a look at this link on Robin Chapman's page:  http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/bertrand.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I have to stick to the proof in the book...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lemma:** $\lfloor 2x \rfloor - 2\lfloor x \rfloor =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \frac12<\{x\}, \\
    0 & 0\le \{x\} \le \frac12.
  \end{cases}$

Here $\{x\}$ denotes the [fractional part](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$.

---

Now if you already know (from the preceding part of the proof) that the exponent of $p$ is 
$$\left\lfloor \frac{2n}p \right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \frac np \right\rfloor$$
then you can use the above lema for $x=\frac np$.

Namely, it is zero whenever $1\le \frac np < \frac32$, which is equivalent to $\frac23n<p\le n$.

---

Note that in that part of the proof you already assume that $p>\sqrt{2n}$, so there is at most one non-zero summand in the sum
$$\sum_{k\ge 1}\left\lfloor \frac{2n}{p^k} \right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \frac n{p^k} \right\rfloor$$

Comment: Different formulation (and proof) of the above lemma can be found in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84121/problem-about-x

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it. One more question: Further down on the page we have

$$\frac{4^n}{2n} \leq \binom{2n}{n} \leq \prod_{p \leq \sqrt{2n}} 2n * \prod_{\sqrt{2n} < p \leq \frac{2}{3}n} p * \prod_{n<p \leq 2n} p$$

The author leaves out $\frac{2}{3}n<p\leq n$ because there are no $p's$. But what is the reason he writes $$\prod_{p \leq \sqrt{2n}} 2n$$
All the other products are with $p$ which is understandable, so why not in the first one?

Greetings,
Daniel

---

Let us denote $a(p)$ the exponent of $p$ in $\binom{2n}n$. The inequality
$$p^{a(p)} \le 2n$$
follows from $a(p)\le \max \{r; p^r\le 2n\}$. (Note that this inequality is mentioned in the proof.)

The proof of the last inequality:
We have
$$a(p)=\sum_{k\ge 1}\left\lfloor \frac{2n}{p^k} \right\rfloor - 2\left\lfloor \frac n{p^k} \right\rfloor$$
and the summand is zero for $k> \max\{r; p^r\le 2n\}$ and all summands are at most one. 
So we have
$$a(p) \le \sum_{k; p^k\le 2n} 1 = \max \{r; p^r\le 2n\}.$$

Therefore we have $$\prod_{p\le\sqrt{2n}} p^{a(p)} \le \prod_{p\le\sqrt{2n}} 2n.$$

Greetings,
 
Martin

Comment: I believe that it would be better to edit your original question and add this there than to post a complementary question as a new answer. (It does not matter so much, but making a habit of this would not be a good thing.)

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your time and effort. I thought the same, so next time, I open a new question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Just to get it right: Because $a(p) \leq max\{r;p^r \leq 2n\}$ I can write $$\prod_{p \leq \sqrt{2n}} 2n$$ and not $$\prod_{p \leq \sqrt{2n}} p$$?

Comment: I would say that $\prod_{p\le\sqrt{2n}} p^{a(p)}$ can be estimated by $\prod_{p\le\sqrt{2n}} 2n$ - see my last edit. With the exception of the missing exponent I agree with what you wrote.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the explanation :)