# On prime factors of $n^2+1$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

It is a well-known conjecture that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$. However, there are weaker results that one can prove. For example,

> There are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ has
>   a prime divisor greater than $2n+\sqrt{2n}$.

This was Problem N6 in IMO 2008 Shortlist. See solution [here](http://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2008SL.pdf) (in page 50). It is remarked there that by tools of analytic number theory (using distribution of prime numbers of the form $4k+1$ somehow), one can show something considerably stronger, namely:

> **Theorem.** There are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ has
>   a prime divisor greater than $n\log(n)$.

I would appreciate if someone gave a proof of the **Theorem** or provide a reference where it is proved.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this answer I will prove that for any $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ with $p>(1-\epsilon)n\log n$ and $p\mid n^2+1$. The idea is to bound the product $$H(N)=\prod_{n\leq N}(n^{2}+1)$$ in two different ways, and is similar in spirit to Erdős' proof of Chebyshev's inequalities${}^{**}$.

**Lower bound:** Notice that $$H(N)\geq\prod_{n\leq N}n^{2}=(N!)^{2}\geq N^{2N}/e^{2N-2},$$ and so $$\log(H(N))\geq2N\log N-(2N-2). \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

**Upper bound:** This is the meat of the argument. Lets assume that $H(N)$  has no prime divisor greater than a parameter $w$ which is chosen so that $w>N$. Our end goal is to show that $w$ cannot be too small, as this implies that $n^2+1$ will have large prime divisors for some $n$. Writing $H(N)$ as a product of primes, we have $$H(N)=\prod_{p\leq w}p^{\alpha_{p}}$$ for some coefficients $\alpha_{p}$. Each prime $p>x$ can divide $n^{2}+1$ for at most two different values of $n$, and so we see that $\alpha_{p}\leq2$ in this case. For $p\leq x$, if $p\mid n^{2}+1$, then $n^{2}\equiv-1\text{ mod }p$. This congruence can only be solved when $p\equiv1\text{ mod }4$, and in that case there will be at most $2\lceil N/p\rceil$  values of $n$ for which $p\mid n^{2}+1$. Similarly, if $p^{k}\mid n^{2}+1$, then $n^{2}\equiv-1\text{ mod }p^{k}$, and there are at most $\gcd(\phi(p^{k}),2)=2$ solutions to this congruence, and hence at most $2\lceil N/p^{k}\rceil$  values of $n$ for which $p^{k}\mid n^{2}+1$. Putting this all together, we find that for $p\leq N$, and $$p\equiv1\text{ mod }4 ,\alpha_{p}\leq2\left\lceil\frac{N}{p}\right\rceil+2\left\lceil\frac{N}{p^{2}}\right\rceil+2\left\lceil\frac{N}{p^{3}}\right\rceil+\cdots+2\left\lceil\frac{N}{p^{k}}\right\rceil$$ where $k=\left\lceil\log_{p}N\right\rceil.$ Using the upper bound $\left\lceil x\right\rceil\leq x+1,$ we obtain  $$\alpha_{p}\leq\frac{2N}{p-1}+2\left(\log_{p}(N)+1\right)$$ since $1+\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^{2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{p^{k}}\leq\frac{1}{1-1/p}.$ Thus, $$H(N)\leq\prod_{\begin{array}{c}
p\leq N\\
p\equiv1\text{ mod }4
\end{array}}p^{\frac{2N}{p-1}+2\log_{p}(N)+2}\prod_{\begin{array}{c}
N<p\leq w\\
p\equiv1\text{ mod }4
\end{array}}p^{2},$$ and so, noting that $p^{\log_{p}(N)}=N,$ we have $$H(N)\leq\prod_{\begin{array}{c}
p\leq N\\
p\equiv1\text{ mod }4
\end{array}}N^{2}\prod_{\begin{array}{c}
p\leq N\\
p\equiv1\text{ mod }4
\end{array}}p^{\frac{2N}{p-1}}\prod_{\begin{array}{c}
p\leq w\\
p\equiv1\text{ mod }4
\end{array}}p^{2}.$$ Taking the logarithm it follows that $$\log H(N)\leq2\pi(N;4,1)\log N+2N\sum_{\begin{array}{c}
p\leq N\\
p\equiv1\text{ mod }4
\end{array}}\frac{\log p}{p-1}+2\theta(w;4,1).$$ By using the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions, we have the asymptotics $\sum_{p\leq N,\ p\equiv1\ (4)}\frac{\log p}{p-1}\sim\frac{1}{2}\log N$, $\theta(w;4,1)\sim w/2$  and $\pi(N;4,1)\log N\sim N/2$, and so $$\log H(N)\lesssim N\log N+w.\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

---

Combining equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ together, it follows that $$2N\log N-(2N-2)\leq\log H(N)\lesssim N\log N+w,$$ and hence for $N>N_0(\epsilon)$ we must have $$(1-\epsilon)N\log N\leq w.$$ Since $w$ cannot be taken to smaller, this implies that for any $\epsilon>0$, we can take $N$ large enough so that there exists $p>(1-\epsilon)N\log N$ such that $p\mid H(N)$. It follows that for any $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many  primes $p$ such that $$p>(1-\epsilon) n\log n \text{ and } p\mid n^{2}+1.$$

---

${}^{**}$  See these three answers for more details on proving Chebyshevs estimates in a similar fashion: [Chebyshev: Proof $\prod \limits_{p \leq 2k}{\;} p > 2^k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95766/chebyshev-proof-prod-limits-p-leq-2k-p-2k/95783#95783),  [Are there any Combinatoric proofs of Bertrand's postulate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38917/are-there-any-combinatoric-proofs-of-bertrands-postulate/38954#38954) and [How to prove Chebyshev's result: $\sum_{p\leq n} \frac{\log p}{p} \sim\log n $ as $n\to\infty$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/how-to-prove-chebyshevs-result-sum-p-leq-n-frac-log-pp-sim-log-n-a/33995#33995)

For a similar question and solution, see this answer: [Squares in $(\operatorname{rad}(1)^2+1)\cdot(\operatorname{rad}(2)^2+1)\ldots(\operatorname{rad}(n)^2+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298823/squares-in-operatornamerad121-cdot-operatornamerad221-ldots-o/2338694#2338694)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think this might have been the intended solution for this problem.

Comment: Hey. Great answer! But there is a typo: You have written $x$ instead of $N$ at two places. I think you have also forgotten to account for the factors of $2$ appearing in $H(N)$. Since a number of the form $n^2+1$ is never divisible by 4, you would get $ H(N) \le 2^{\frac{N+1}{2}} \prod \limits_{\substack{p \; \le \; N \\ p \equiv 1(\text{mod}\; 4)}} p^{\frac{2N}{p-1}+2\log_{p}(N)+2} \prod \limits_{\substack{N \; <p\le \; w \\ p \equiv 1 (\text{mod}\; 4)}} p^{2}$, right? (Not that it matters for the conclusion, though..)

Comment: Also, I think $k=\lceil \log_p(N)\rceil$ should be $k=\lfloor \log_p(N^2+1)\rfloor$. For example, the congruence $k^2\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\; 13^m)$ restricted to $0\le k\le 240$ is solvable for $m$ up to $4$ (since $239^2+1=2\cdot 13^4$). Here $\lfloor \log_{13}(240^2+1)\rfloor=4$, while $\lceil \log_{13}(240)\rceil=3$.

Answer (score 8):

Even better: [Deshouillers and Iwaniec (1982)](http://aif.cedram.org/item?id=AIF_1982__32_4_1_0) have shown that there are infinitely many positive integers $n$ such that $n^2+1$ has a prime factor greater than $n^{6/5}$.

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Very nice reference. That said, I hope to see somewhat more elementary argument for $n\log(n)$. :)

Comment: Take a look at this paper http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa74/aa7432.pdf and its references.  Chebysheff and/or Nagell may have what you want, but I can't find an online copy of their proofs.

Comment: This paper is perhaps even better for you: http://eprints.maths.ox.ac.uk/165/1/x3%2B2.pdf